# Local search in CFG algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, context-free-grammar

Is there an algorithm that can solve the following problem in polynomial time:

We are connecting bits in bitset:

- 0 can only be connected to 1
- each bit can be connected only once
- the connections can't intersect

What is the maximum amount of connections for a given bitset?

Comment: As a way to approach this problem I would first look at the scenario with only A's and B's. Can you make a polytime algorithm for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use dynamic programming here.

1. The state is `(l, r)` - a `[l, r]` substring of the given string.
2. The value of the state is the maximum number of matching symbols within the substring.
3. The base case is trivial: for all substrings shorter than 2, the answer 0.
4. For all longer substrings, we can do two things:

   - Do not match the first symbol to anything.
   - Match it to something and solve two smaller subproblems independently(they are independent because intersection are not allowed).

That's it. The time complexity is `O(n^3)`(there are `O(n^2)` states and `O(n)` transitions from each of them). Here is a pseudo code(memoization is omitted for brevity):

```
def calc(l, r)
    if l >= r
        return 0
    res = calc(l + 1, r)
    for k = l + 1 to r
        if match(s[l], s[k]) // match checks that two characters match
            res = max(res, 1 + calc(l + 1, k - 1) + calc(k + 1, r)) 
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the maximum amount of connections in a given sequence of 0s and 1s is the minimum of these two values - number of 0s in sequence and number of 1s in sequence.

There isn't a case when you could not connect all of the bits that are in the minority. So this problem can be solved in O(n).